# Magento 2 Custom Theme development

Tags: magento2, theme

Is there a repo out there with a solid custom theme for Magento 2? I'm looking for educational purposes. I learn better by looking at the code vs reading a mile long blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the blank and luma themes are just made for this ;)

the blank theme to show how you can create some sort of a base theme and the luma theme for how to extend the base theme

I think you will get pretty good results by copying the luma theme and starting your own with this as a base.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento

Comment: What about header/ footer phtml? Magento_Theme/templates/html folder?

Comment: Hi David, page not found while click on the above link